# db_fetch_array() fetches only one row from data table, even though I am expecting multiple results

Tags: organic-groups, database

I'm trying to create an array with all the group node' IDs, and from outside group context.
I currently have two group nodes defined, and I can see them in my OG table.

However I only get back one result, using the following code. I've tried using only `db_query()` without `db_fetch_array()` and I still get a single result.

```
$group_node_nids = db_fetch_array(db_query("SELECT nid from {og}"));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is wrong; you should use the following one:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {og}");

while ($group = db_fetch_array($query)) {
  // Do something with $group['nid'], such as storing it in an array,
  // or directly using it.
}
```

[db_fetch_array()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_fetch_array/6) doesn't return an array containing all the rows matching the query; it returns only one row. If you want to get all the results, you need to keep calling that function.

In this specific case, as you are just fetching a field, you should use [db_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_result/6).

```
$query = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {og}");

while ($nid = db_result($query)) {
  // Do something with $nid, which is the node ID for the group.
}
```

`db_result()` should be used also in cases similar to the following one, where the query is returning a single value:

```
$max = db_result(db_query('SELECT MAX(thread) FROM {comments} WHERE nid = %d', $edit['nid']));
```

Instead of `MAX(thread)` you could also use `COUNT(*)` as in the following code, which returns the number of groups present in the site:

```
$number_of_groups = db_select(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {og}"));
```

Comment: Thank you for yet another thorough and informative answer. It of course solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Every time I have to take results outs of a database query result resource I'm scratching my head wondering why we don't have a way to return all rows without having to iterate over the object.  Perhaps there's a method out there in cTools or Drupal 7 but until a better answer is presented:

```
$results = db_query("SELECT nid from {og}");
while($row = db_fetch_array($results)) { 
  $group_node_nids[] = $row['nid'];
}
```

Comment: Hm, not sure how formatting code on SE works yet.

Comment: The Drupal functions are thin wrappers around the php db functions. This is the same even in D7